# Regex to validate a url using a wildcard?

Tags: regex, url, language-agnostic

Lets say I have a list of valid domain roots,

`example.com`

`test.com`

And a variable

`String url`

How would I make use of a regex to validate that my variable url is on the list, including subdomains?

For example, perhaps my url is `"subdomain.case.example.com"`

That is, to say clearly:

How would I utilize a regex to verify that my url is `*.example.com` OR `*.test.com` OR `example.com` OR `test.com`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

```
^((\*|[\w\d]+(-[\w\d]+)*)\.)*(example|test)(\.com)$
```

[image: Regular expression image]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/xOD3eBBPYnQq8Rb9)

To allow for such things as...  subdomain.*.example.com, subdomain.example.com, example.com, *.example.com, etc.

Comment: I think so, I'll let you know if this does what I want!

I would just like to say that this debuggex tool is freaking sweet and I've never seen it before.

Comment: I missed an `+` after the `[\w\d-]`... updated post... also made it so that parts cannot start or end with a dash

Comment: If you have a sec for a quick question, if I am doing this in java do I have to escape every \ ?

Comment: yes, you do have to do that in java. also, if you go to this site http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html and enter the regex and click test, it will convert to java regex

Answer (score 0):

Use `$` to mark the end of string.

Your regex would be

```
.*(example|test)[.]com$
```

Comment: That also matches `notanexample.com`. The standard way to match a literal `.` character is to use a backslash like `\.`.